# Reading out json file, checking if keys are existing and using their values

Tags: python, json

My goal is to check a json file if some keys exist and if true, using its values. My first approach was with standart json lib, and the json file:

```
{
  "M65 PRO RGB": 1,
  "K55 RGB": 2
}
```

I did this:

```
from os import times
from config import config_from_json
from cuesdk import CueSdk
import json
import sacn
import time

sdk = CueSdk() #Corsair iCue SDK
sdk.connect()
sdk.set_layer_priority(128)
with open('config.json') as f:  #Config
      conf = json.load(f)
      print(conf)

device_count = sdk.get_device_count() #setup Corsair devices config



for device_index in range(device_count):
    device_name = sdk.get_device_info(device_index)
    exists = device_name in conf
    print(exists)
    if exists == False:
        print(f"Device {device_name} not found")
```

But with this, the keys are read out as `'M65 PRO RGB'` and `'K55 RGGB'` instead of just plain `M65 PRO RGB` and `K55 RGB`.`device_name` can be `M65 PRO RGB`, `K55 RGB`, `H100i PLATINUM` or `Lighting Node CORE`.  So ofcourse is `exists = False`. I dont know anything about string manipulation and tried another aproach with the lib python-config and re-arrenged my json to this:

```
{
    "1": {
        "name": "M65 PRO RGB",
        "universe": 1
    },
    "2": {
        "name": "K55 RGB",
        "universe": 2
    },
    "3": {
        "name": "H100i",
        "universe": 3
    }   
}
```

Now i wanna iterate trhough the keys 1,2,3 and check if the value of the key `name` is present and if true, return the value from `universe`, else iterate from the key `1` to the next.I went with

```
def check_config_for_device(device_name):
      key_count = len(cfg.keys())
      for i in range(key_count):
       if  cfg[i].name == device_name:
           print("found")
           return cfg[i].universe 
sdk = CueSdk() #Corsair iCue SDK
sdk.connect()
sdk.set_layer_priority(128)
#with open('config.json') as f:  #Config
#      conf = json.load(f)
#      print(conf)

device_count = sdk.get_device_count() #setup Corsair devices config



for device_index in range(device_count):
    device_name = sdk.get_device_info(device_index)
    universe = check_config_for_device(device_name)
    setup_receiver(universe, device_index)
```

Now i get this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\tenn0\Documents\Projects\icue2sacn\src\main.py", line 64, in <module>
    universe = check_config_for_device(device_name)
  File "c:\Users\tenn0\Documents\Projects\icue2sacn\src\main.py", line 38, in check_config_for_device
    if  cfg[i].name == device_name:
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\config\configuration.py", line 152, in __getitem__
    v = self._get_subset(item)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\config\configuration.py", line 132, in _get_subset
    d = {
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\config\configuration.py", line 135, in <dictcomp>
    if k.startswith(prefix + ".")
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

If i convert `i` to a string by altering `check_config_for_device` to

```
      key_count = len(cfg.keys())
      for i in range(key_count):
       iStr = str(i)
       if  cfg[iStr].name == device_name:
           print("found")
           return cfg[i].universe
```

i get This:

```
  File "c:\Users\tenn0\Documents\Projects\icue2sacn\src\main.py", line 65, in <module>
    universe = check_config_for_device(device_name)
  File "c:\Users\tenn0\Documents\Projects\icue2sacn\src\main.py", line 39, in check_config_for_device
    if  cfg[iStr].name == device_name:
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\config\configuration.py", line 155, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(item)
KeyError: '0'
```

I dont know any further, how to fix this or work around it.

Comment: When you say that: `keys are read out as 'M65 PRO RGB'` what is each `device_name`?

Comment: basically, just `M65 PRO RGB` without the single quotation marks. Ive edited the post to  include all current possible values of `device_name`

Comment: And so the line `print(conf)` produces basically the same as the first snippet? I am expecting that `device_name in conf` should work. So each `device_name` is a `str` right?

Comment: i think yes, but calling `print(type(device_name))` returns `<class 'cuesdk.api.Device'>`. Do you refer to the first approach with the normal json lib?

Comment: So what is a `cuesdk.api.Device`? Does it have a `name` attribute or similar you could use? (ie `device_name.name in conf`)?

Comment: Yep. `device_name.model in conf` returns the correct things. Gonna work on tzhe code to utilize this to retrive the value from the key, but actually i began to like the new json file structure, so that i can write different settings like mqtt settings and so on into the same file while having it easier to read by humans